# Can a Bokeh server be run in the Jupyter extension of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, vscode-extensions, content-security-policy

I have VS Code installed together with the Jupyter extension. I have Jupyter and Bokeh locally installed on my computer too.

VS Code:
Version: 1.51.1
Commit: e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f
Date: 2020-11-10T23:31:29.624Z
Electron: 9.3.3
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.4.0-56-generic

ms-toolsai.jupyter: v2020.12.411183155

jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : 4.7.5
ipython          : 7.16.1
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
jupyter client   : 6.1.6
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.7
traitlets        : 4.3.3

bokeh: 2.1.1

I am trying to run in VS Code a notebook that launches a Bokeh server in order to create then an interactive web application, as in the example below:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook

output_notebook()

def plot(doc):
    x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,20)
    y = np.sin(x)

    p = figure()
    h = p.line(x, y)

    doc.add_root(p)

show(plot)
```

When I start Jupyter from a terminal and runs that notebook in a web-browser, everything works fine.

When I use the Jupyter extension in VS Code and display a simple Bokeh figure (using bokeh.io.show(bokeh.plotting.figure)), everything works fine too.

This is when I use the Jupyter extension in VS Code and try to work with a Bokeh server (using bokeh.io.show(callable) as in the example above) that things fail, and that I get the following message in the Webview developer console:

> VM79:809 Refused to connect to
> 'ws://localhost:33727/ws?platform=electron' because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src
> 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: https: http: blob:
> vscode-webview-resource:". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly
> set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback. VM79:809 [bokeh] Failed
> to connect to Bokeh server: Could not open websocket VM79:808 [bokeh]
> Failed to load Bokeh session
> vAIAgpYICYGtqkteUPnD9UbYsp0oXOzsb9lZbLUVOFk4: Error: Could not open
> websocket

I tried to uncheck the "Use Default Config for Jupyter" option in the Jupyter extension settings, and specify the following content security policy in the ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py file:

```
c.NotebookApp.tornado_settings = {
    'headers': {
        'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: http: https: ws: wss: blob: vscode-webview-resource:; connect-src http: https: ws: wss:"
    }
}
```

but that surprisingly had no influence (while modifying these settings and running Jupyter in the web-browser had the influence as expected).

I also tried to launch a local Jupyter server from a terminal and make the VS Code Jupyter extension connect to that server (instead of letting VS Code start the Jupyter server by itself), but this surprisingly had no influence either.

Has anybody any ideas what can go wrong ? Has anybody already achieved what I try to do ?

I've already spent a few days attempting to fix the issue and I am now clueless.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a [recent issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10765) about this. It is not yet clear whether integration with VSCode is possible, or not. Bokeh expects to be able to make an HTTP connection that it upgrades to a websocket connection, and also to be able to to execute JS code, and it seems as though VSCode may interfere with those requirements. Please feel free to add this information to the linked issue above, since it seems like a novel failure path.

Comment: Yes it looks like this is the same issue - bad news because there doesn't seem to be any ways to fix the problem for now. I've added a comment in the linked GitHub issue as you suggested.